# Hide a div if an element has been clicked twice in a row, else Show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several items in my navigation bar, and a `div` next to it, ie:

```
<nav>
  <a id="a"></a>
  <a id="b"></a>
  <a id="c"></a>
</nav>
<div id="menu-col"></div>
```

If the same link is clicked twice in a row, I want to hide `#menu-col`. If not, I want `#menu-col` to remain visible.

I'm not a javascript guy so I tried this:

```
var lastClicked;
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id + " - " + this.lastClicked);
    if (e.target.id == this.lastClicked) {
        $('#menu-col').hide();
        this.lastClicked = '';
    }
    else {
        $('#menu-col').show();
        this.lastClicked = e.target.id;
    }
});
```

Then I remembered that javascript assigns references, and not values. So when I did `this.lastClicked = e.target.id;` I'm assigning a reference to my element's id, then on the next click I make that `e.target.id == ''`.

In javascript, what would be the proper way of closing a box if the same link is clicked twice, and if not making sure the box is visible.

Comment: `$('#menu-col').hide();` should be `$('.menu-col').hide();` because it's a class, not an id, unless you want to make it an id

Comment: Do you really mean 2 times in a row (without a certain time period in between?) or a double click? Because you could use https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ then

Comment: @depperm my bad that was a typo, fixing now.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski two times in a row, not a double click. the div is hidden on start up, I want it to open when the user clicks a link once, if he clicks the same link again after ie: 2 minutes, the div should close.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `toggleClass()` to set a state class on the clicked `a` and also using `toggle()` on the `.menu-col` to show or hide it based on that state class. Try this:

```js
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $a = $(this);
  $a.toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('.menu-col').toggle($a.hasClass('active'));
});
```

```css
.menu-col {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a id="a" href="#">a</a>
  <a id="b" href="#">b</a>
  <a id="c" href="#">c</a>
</nav>
<div class="menu-col">menu-col</div>
```

Comment: @AWolff I take it to mean that on the first click of an element the div is shown. Only hide on the second repeated click of the element. So if you click `a`, `b`, `a` the div will be visible all the time. If you click `a` again it should then hide.

Comment: Ya and i guess it is what OP is expecting. +1

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep those ids unique across you app (which you should be doing anyway) the approach you've chosen isn't wrong. Any primitive in javascript is actually stored by value. Those primitives are string, number, boolean, and symbol. For more info see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this, you should have some kind of condition in which the div shows after it has been hidden.

```
$('nav a').dblclick(function(event) {
    event.preventDefualt();
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    $('#menu-col').toggle();
});
```

Something like that should be exactly what you are looking for, like I said though, there should be a condition in which it shows itself again, I made it a toggle so any double click on any 'nav a' element will cause it to show/hide the div.

Answer (score -1):

Just for the sake of an option. Here is another way for double clicks(clicked twice in a row).

Using `ondblclick` event.

```html
<a href="#" ondblclick="console.log('Double clicked!');">Double-click me.</a>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Dont care about the downvote, but the reason. Is anything wrong here?